# Is there a way to run the program (using keyboard shortcut) in the activated tab in PyCharm / IntelliJ / Clion?

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm, clion

The current problem is that I have two Tabs. Tab 1 and Tab 2.
When I run the program in tab 1 using the shortcut then it runs the program in Tab 1. 
But when I switch the view to tab 2 and use the shortcut to run the program in tab 2, the last run program, that means the program in tab 1 gets executed.

But this time I wanted to run the program in the current tab.

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

In PyCharm / IntelliJ, you can run a tab you are currently on by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>.

To run tab you last executed, you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>, no matter on what tab you're on.

Comment: Hi @vostro.beta if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.